# Why panel2 didnt remove the chartpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

In my Java application, I just use two different panels named as `Panel1`, `Panel2`. Both panels have their own `ChartPanel` from `JFreeChart` to generate dynamic chart. If I want to clear this by using,

```
    if(Panel1.getComponentCount() != 0) Panel1.remove(Graph.CPanel);
    if(Panel2.getComponentCount() != 0) Panel2.remove(Graph1.CPanel1);
    Panel1.repaint();
    Panel2.repaint();
```

the above code mean, it just remove panel one content. Panel two still show the chart panel, but that's not running. Why panel two didn't remove its content?

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: This code is not sufficient to resolve your concern.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  But do the MCVE using simple colored (JSE) panels first.

Comment: @Rahul  Generally best to point the OP to the MCVE/MCTR document at times like this, otherwise we tend to get bits and pieces of uncompilable code snippets.

Comment: @Rahul, then can you give sample code to remocve chartpanel from the jpanel?

Answer (score 2):

While you can chose to *remove* the view component, which requires `revalidate()`, a better choice is to *update* the model and let the view respond. Some related examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284838/230513).

Answer (score 0):

```
      Panel1.removeAll();
      Panel2.removeAll();
```

The above statements remove all components in those panels successfully.